# How to set the color of Log in Android Studio Run window?

Tags: android-studio

I had accidentally successfully set the color of statements printed by `android.util.log` before, but I forgot how to do it.

The effect is as follows, the output of `Debug` level is highlighted.

[image]

I export settings from Android Studio, found a suspected option, but I can't find this setting in the interface.

```xml
<scheme name="_@user_Darcula" version="142" parent_scheme="Darcula">
  <metaInfo>
    <property name="created">2023-01-02T20:44:03</property>
    <property name="ide">AndroidStudio</property>
    <property name="ideVersion">2021.3.1.17</property>
    <property name="modified">2023-04-06T15:41:39</property>
    <property name="originalScheme">Darcula</property>
  </metaInfo>
  <attributes>
    <option name="LOGCAT_DEBUG_OUTPUT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="7778e3" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="LOGCAT_V2_MESSAGE_VERBOSE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="ee4866" />
      </value>
    </option>
  </attributes>
</scheme>
```

I think a possible setting is `<option name="LOGCAT_DEBUG_OUTPUT">`

How should it be set? **Note that it is `Run Window` not `Logcat Window`**